# How do i sort in perl my hash array on the key?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a calendar filled with daily hours from persons.
I like to sort my hours per day.. i already counted the hours.

```
loop....
    # $daguren  1..31
    # uren = sum of all the daily hours
    $daguren{$dag} += $workedhours;
...loop

# i like to sort it on "daguren" that is a number 1 .. 31   
while (($dag,$uren)=each %daguren){
    print "dag=$dag uren=$uren<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to iterate over the keys

```
# This sorts by working hours
my @sorted_keys = sort { $daguren{$a} <=> $daguren{$b} } keys %daguren;

# This sorts by date
my @sorted_keys = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %daguren;

foreach my $dag ( @sorted_keys )
{
     my $uren = $daguren{$dag};
     print "dag=$dag uren=$uren<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that you can't sort a hash, but you can sort the keys of a hash.  For more see [the Perl FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)%3f)

Comment: I don't understand..  i do not have the first value? (1..31 days)  or am i wrong?

Comment: No. Hashes are unsorted. If you want to work with a hash in a sorted order, you must first retrieve a list of the hash keys, sort those, and then iterate over those sorted keys. I edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: This did the Job... thanks i appreciate it very much